# can I implement DR site on google cloude for a site on digital ocean?

Tags: kubernetes

I have all my sites on digital ocean. We use Digital ocean block storage for that purpose. The question is, can I implement all the DR sites on google cloud "GCP" ? As in taking Kubernetes volume from digital ocean and use it to create the DR site on GCP. Is that doable in this way? or are there any other ways to accomplish this requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly? You want to do Disaster Recovery of current deployments that is in Digital Ocean and deploy it on GCP? Is it deployed in k8s?

Comment: Hi Crou, yes that is the case

Comment: I'm not sure if Disaster Recovery in two separate Cloud environments is smart.
It would be much easier to implement if you stayed with Digital Ocean but expand into a different region.

But if you like to have a copy of your current `Deployment` inside GCP then there is nothing holding you back.
If you are not using any DO specific features like for example Load Balancer and Block Storage then it would be as easy as just copying all your `.yaml` files over to GCP and applying them.
How will you switch DR on, when DO dies?